# Python - Entry value in foor loops - How to update the starting values

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to trying to make a little Tkinter GUI according to a Python tutorial.

The idea is to:

1. Have some NAMES - Have some entries with START VALUES - Multiply them with a FIXED VALUE
2. Change the entry START VALUE - Multiply again with a FIXED VALUE (when I click the button)

Here is the code (Python 3.7.5)

```
from tkinter import *
import math

class main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = Tk()
        self.main.title("StackOverflow Question")
        self.main.geometry('200x200')
        self.main.configure(bg="White")

        names = ['John', 'Paul', 'Jones']
        values = [10.0, 20.0, 30.5]

        labelTitle = Label(self.main, font=('Arial', 12), text = "Names", bg="White", justify = CENTER)
        labelTitle.place(x=10, y=10)

        valuesList = []
        for i in range(len(names)):
            labelNames = Label(self.main, text = names[i], bg="White", justify = CENTER)
            labelNames.place(x=10, y=30 + i * 20)

            var = DoubleVar()
            var.set(values[i])
            valuesNames = Entry(self.main, textvariable=var, width=8, bg='light gray', bd = 0, justify = CENTER)
            valuesNames.place(x=70, y=30 + i * 20)
            valuesList.append(valuesNames.get())


        def formula():
            for i in range(len(names)):
                multiplier = 1000
                valueMultiplied = float(valuesList[i])* multiplier
                valueMultipliedEntry = Entry(self.main, width=8, bg='light gray', bd = 0, justify = CENTER)
                valueMultipliedEntry.insert(END, valueMultiplied)
                valueMultipliedEntry.place(x=130, y=30 + i * 20)



        btn1 = Button(self.main, text="Calculate", command=formula)
        btn1.place(x=70, y=100)

        mainloop()

main()
```

Thank you very much, and sorry for the beginner question.

**EDIT:**

The question is that the values that I .get() from the Entry are fixed, and if I change them, the and click the button btn1, it still doesn't calculate.
Can you please help?

thank you very much.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and edit your question accordingly - ATM it's quite unclear what your problem is.

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven_programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Read through [`[tkinter] event driven programming`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+event+driven+programming+entry)

Comment: Thank you all. I made an edit to the post, because it was lacking the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some more things ...
you can write in there

```
btn1 = Button(self.main, text="Calculate", command=lambda:formula())
```

Comment: Thank you. But it did not work. It still calculates with the original entry values  (values = [10.0, 20.0, 30.5]) even if I change the entry values.